# Hex file reading in C programming?

Tags: c, file, io, hex, hexdump

I had a question:

I am writing a c program that functions much like a hex editor. I want to take in a file and view its hexadecimal values. For example, say I had the text file "helloworld.txt" that simply had the words "Hello World!" in it, I want to specify to the program to take that file, read its hexidecimal values (again the file is a simple .txt file and not a binary file) and store it in an array for later.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   gets(file_name);

   fp = fopen(file_name,"rb"); // read binary mode

   if( fp == NULL ) //error checking
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
      printf("%c",ch);

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see this is really just a simple file in, read and print contents. However, the problem is that even though I'm in "read binary" mode, it won't give me the hexadecimal values of the text file.

> How can I structure this program so that it reads the hexadecimal values of a standard text file and either (a) puts them in an array (which I think should be simple enough with a for loop) or (b) prints them out to the screen?

I tried googling to see if others were trying to do the same thing, but people were either already reading from a binary file or already had hexadecimal values in the file. I have plain text in a regular .txt file, but I want the hexadecimal values underneath (in other words a sort of hexdump of the file). I hope my question and what I'm trying to do makes sense. If you have any questions please feel free to let me know! Thanks in advance for all your help! I really do appreciate it!

Comment: **Never use gets().**

Comment: And...it's just a matter of representation, you `printf("%c", ch);`, so you get char format; do like `printf("%02X", ch);`, you get hex value.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but wouldn't that be the case (for option B) of simply using

```
printf("0X%02x ", ch);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply and help! What is the difference between your printf statement and moeCake 's printf statement in the comments above? and I can use that same method to output those hex values to an array?

Comment: There's no difference really - all I am doing is printing "0X" in front of the hex byte and a space after it, so you get something like "0XAA 0X2E" and in moeCake's suggestion you get "AA2E".

Comment: As far as putting the values in an array, depends on what you want to do - if you want to write the actual binary byte value of the character, then use asamarin method below. If you want to write the textual representation of the bytes (ie "0XAA "), then you probably want to use fprintf - just remember that the size of the array will be the number of bytes in your source file times 5.

Answer (score 1):

You are so very close.
Notice 2 things:

1- Use of fgets() instead of gets().
2- printf("%02X ",ch);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   fgets(file_name, sizeof(file_name), stdin);
   file_name[strlen(file_name)-1] = 0x00;

   fp = fopen(file_name,"rb"); // read binary mode

   if( fp == NULL ) //error checking
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

   int i;
   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
   {
      printf("%02X ",ch);
      if( !(++i % 16) ) putc('\n', stdout);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   putc('\n', stdout);

   return 0;
}
```

Of course this just prints to stdout. If you want to put the result into
an array you could something like `sprintf()` to put your output into some buffer(s).

Example output:

```
jrn@mint17 ~ $ ./a.out 
Enter the name of file you wish to see
hex_for_so.c
The contents of hex_for_so.c file are :
23 69 6E 63 6C 75 64 65 20 3C 73 74 64 69 6F 2E 
68 3E 0A 23 69 6E 63 6C 75 64 65 20 3C 73 74 64 
6C 69 62 2E 68 3E 0A 23 69 6E 63 6C 75 64 65 20 
3C 73 74 72 69 6E 67 2E 68 3E 0A 0A 69 6E 74 20 
6D 61 69 6E 28 29 0A 7B 0A 20 20 20 63 68 61 72 
20 63 68 2C 20 66 69 6C 65 5F 6E 61 6D 65 5B 32 
35 5D 3B 0A 20 20 20 46 49 4C 45 20 2A 66 70 3B 
0A 0A 20 20 20 70 72 69 6E 74 66 28 22 45 6E 74 
65 72 20 74 68 65 20 6E 61 6D 65 20 6F 66 20 66 
69 6C 65 20 79 6F 75 20 77 69 73 68 20 74 6F 20 
73 65 65 5C 6E 22 29 3B 0A 20 20 20 66 67 65 74 
73 28 66 69 6C 65 5F 6E 61 6D 65 2C 20 73 69 7A 
65 6F 66 28 66 69 6C 65 5F 6E 61 6D 65 29 2C 20 
73 74 64 69 6E 29 3B 0A 20 20 20 66 69 6C 65 5F 
6E 61 6D 65 5B 73 74 72 6C 65 6E 28 66 69 6C 65 
5F 6E 61 6D 65 29 2D 31 5D 20 3D 20 30 78 30 30 
3B 0A 0A 20 20 20 66 70 20 3D 20 66 6F 70 65 6E 
28 66 69 6C 65 5F 6E 61 6D 65 2C 22 72 62 22 29 
3B 20 2F 2F 20 72 65 61 64 20 62 69 6E 61 72 79 
20 6D 6F 64 65 0A 0A 20 20 20 69 66 28 20 66 70 
20 3D 3D 20 4E 55 4C 4C 20 29 20 2F 2F 65 72 72 
6F 72 20 63 68 65 63 6B 69 6E 67 0A 20 20 20 7B 
0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 70 65 72 72 6F 72 28 22 45 
72 72 6F 72 20 77 68 69 6C 65 20 6F 70 65 6E 69 
6E 67 20 74 68 65 20 66 69 6C 65 2E 5C 6E 22 29 
3B 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 65 78 69 74 28 45 58 49 
54 5F 46 41 49 4C 55 52 45 29 3B 0A 20 20 20 7D 
0A 0A 20 20 20 70 72 69 6E 74 66 28 22 54 68 65 
20 63 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 73 20 6F 66 20 25 73 20 
66 69 6C 65 20 61 72 65 20 3A 5C 6E 22 2C 20 66 
69 6C 65 5F 6E 61 6D 65 29 3B 0A 0A 20 20 20 69 
6E 74 20 69 3B 0A 20 20 20 77 68 69 6C 65 28 20 
28 20 63 68 20 3D 20 66 67 65 74 63 28 66 70 29 
20 29 20 21 3D 20 45 4F 46 20 29 0A 20 20 20 7B 
0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 70 72 69 6E 74 66 28 22 25 
30 32 58 20 22 2C 63 68 29 3B 0A 09 20 20 69 66 
28 20 21 28 2B 2B 69 20 25 20 31 36 29 20 29 20 
70 75 74 63 28 27 5C 6E 27 2C 20 73 74 64 6F 75 
74 29 3B 0A 20 20 20 7D 0A 20 20 20 66 63 6C 6F 
73 65 28 66 70 29 3B 0A 20 20 20 72 65 74 75 72 
6E 20 30 3B 0A 7D 0A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fd;
    long filesize;
    char *buffer, *it;

    if ((fd = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(fd);
    rewind(fd);

    buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * filesize+1);

    if (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), filesize, fd) != filesize) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    buffer[filesize] = '\0';

    for (it = buffer; *it != '\0'; it++)
        printf("%02X ", *it);

    free(buffer);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your help! 
Could you explain this part of the code for me? :
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(fd);
    rewind(fd);
and what could I do differently if I wanted to output these results to an array?

Comment: Sure: The `fseek()`-`ftell()`-`rewind()` block is a rather standard way of obtaining the size of the file you are about to read; this way, you can dynamically allocate the size of your memory buffer to be exactly the same as the file size, no more and no less.
For the array question, you have to notice that `buffer` is already your array! It's just a matter of representation: in each element of the buffer you have one character, that is, 8 bits which make up the ASCII representation of that character. But, at the same time, you can see those 8 bits as 2 hexadecimal symbols (4 bits each) cont'd

Comment: (...) and that's exactly what the `printf()` inside the for loop does, just printing the array values, one element each time, as hexadecimal numbers and not characters. We could have printed them as integer (base 10) numbers instead, and that way you would get something like `72 101 108 108 111` for "Hello". The only thing you really need to understand is that your characters, decimal numbers, hexadecimal numbers -you name it- are already in that `buffer` array since the very moment you read the file from disk; from then on, it's up to you how to interpret that data.