# Hex file reading in C, some data corrupted?

Tags: c

Iam having a problem with my school project. When i try to read in C program some hex data from a binary file i get some data filled with F's like this

```
00 64 61 56 03 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 73 00 00 00 
6A 69 75 FFFFFFE8 FFFFFFD1 5B FFFFFF8C FFFFFF93 73 FFFFFFAF 19 FFFFFF87 FFFFFFC1 4D FFFFFFFD FFFFFF93 
FFFFFFDF FFFFFFBE FFFFFFA0 09 FFFFFFBE FFFFFFD4 FFFFFFEB FFFFFFDE FFFFFFD3 FFFFFFF9 FFFFFFBD FFFFFFE6 FFFFFFFA FFFFFFAA 7E 29 
FFFFFFD3 FFFFFFE2 13 FFFFFFA5 3F FFFFFFA0 3A FFFFFFB2 50 53 3B 12 FFFFFFA1 39 FFFFFFA6 FFFFFF82 
FFFFFFF7
```

While the original file in hexdump looks like this:

```
0000000 6400 5661 0003 0000 0009 0000 0073 0000
0000010 696a e875 5bd1 938c af73 8719 4dc1 93fd
0000020 bedf 09a0 d4be deeb f9d3 e6bd aafa 297e
0000030 e2d3 a513 a03f b23a 5350 123b 39a1 82a6
0000040 00f7
```

Iam not quiet sure, why is this happening.

I tested it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057846/hex-file-reading-in-c-programming) code:

```
int main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   fgets(file_name, sizeof(file_name), stdin);
   file_name[strlen(file_name)-1] = 0x00;

   fp = fopen(file_name,"rb"); // read binary mode

   if( fp == NULL ) //error checking
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

   int i;
   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
   {
      printf("%02X ",ch);
      if( !(++i % 16) ) putc('\n', stdout);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   putc('\n', stdout);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no "hex data". Hexadecimal is just a way of representing data. You can represent the very same data in any other number system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just tripped on the sign extension done by the processor when expanding a signed integer value to a larger integer type:

The type `char` is only one byte wide, while the `printf()` function expects `int` arguments (four bytes on your system). Since `char` is signed on your system, the other 24 bits are filled with copies of the sign bit, producing the `FFFFFF` pattern that you see in your output. Note that your output is correct, except for the `FFFFFF`-prefixes to all bytes that start with a hex digit greater or equal to `8`.

You can avoid this by simply declaring `ch` as `unsigned char`. That will be zero extended to an `int`, and your output will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you make ch an unsigned character you won't see the sign extension (the FFs).

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a good idea to open a file as a **binary** file, and trying reading it by `fgetc()`, which deals with **text** files. Instead, you can use `fread()` to read binary files.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    char file_name[25];
    puts("Enter the name of file you wish to see");
    fgets(file_name, sizeof (file_name), stdin);
    file_name[strlen(file_name) - 1] = '\0';

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "rb"); // read binary mode

    if(!fp) //error checking
    {
        perror("fopen()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END); // non-portable
    long fSize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

    uint8_t *ch = malloc(fSize); // assuming CHAR_BIT == 8
    fread(ch, 1, fSize, fp);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < fSize; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2x ", ch[i]);
        if(!((i + 1) % 16))
            putchar('\n');
    }
    fclose(fp);
    putchar('\n');

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code has been tested on my machine, and its output is identical to that of `hex dump`. Feel free to ask me about the details.

Answer (score 0):

make ch an unsigned char as it is treating the binary value as signed and the MSB as sign bit.